# Is this the right way to split a list into 3 parts based on ratios?

Tags: python

I want to split a list into 3 parts, with a ratio of 80%, 10%, 10%, and this is my code:

```
def split_data(data):
    total = len(data)
    train = int(total * 0.8)
    validation = int(total * 0.1)
    
    train_data = data[0:train]
    validation_data = data[train:train+validation]
    test_data = data[train+validation :]

    return train_data, validation_data, test_data


train_data, validation_data, test_data = split_data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
print(train_data, validation_data, test_data)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [7, 8] [9, 10]
```

It seems working. could there be any flaws?

Comment: If your code works then you should ask your question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If having an unequal number of `validation_data` and `test_data` is a flaw, then yes. Try with `data = list(range(25))` for example. If not, then I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: You should create a test suite that puts your function though its paces and insures it does what you want/expect in all possible situations, including especially any "edge" cases there might be.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Small differences between validation and test are fine.